# Combine column values, and then randomize it

Tags: microsoft-excel

so, what I mean by this is, when you use to combine, usually it will come out like this right?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WlOR.jpg
this is the formula: =A2&C2&E2

but, what i want is to combine it, but the column is random, so it will become like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OapZg.jpg
so column A, Column C, and Column E, will have a randomized position. does this possible?

Comment: If you're ok with the format of Random A, Random C, Random E (always in this order), then you could also try this: =CONCAT(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,RANDBETWEEN(1,ROWS($A$2:$A$7)),1),INDEX($C$2:$C$7,RANDBETWEEN(1,ROWS($C$2:$C$7)),1),INDEX($E$2:$E$7,RANDBETWEEN(1,ROWS($E$2:$E$7)),1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Excel 365, try the following formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,CHOOSE(SORTBY(SEQUENCE(3), RANDARRAY(3)),$A2,$C2,$E2))
```

[image: Result]

Comment: do i have a wrong settings or something? https://i.imgur.com/rwUcXa6.jpg

Comment: @Merlion What version of Excel is installed on your PC?

Comment: this is my version: https://i.imgur.com/hGdn3Vv.jpg

Comment: @Merlion Your version doesn't have the SORTBY, SEQUENCE and RANDARRAY functions.